# Body encoding for multilingual data

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I am currently working on an application that supports multiple languages: English, Spanish, Russian, Polish, etc.

I have set up my SQL server database to have Unicode field types (nvarchar etc).

I am concerned now with setting the correct encoding on the HTML, text, XML files etc. I am aware that it needs to be UTF, but not sure if it's UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32. Could someone explain the difference and which encoding is the best to go with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is about something that is supposed to use web browsers, as it seems, then UTF-8 is the only reasonable choice, since it’s the only encoding that is widely supported in browsers. Regarding the ways to set the encoding, check out the W3C page [Character encodings](http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset.en.php).